# SVG backgrounds would not stretch disproportionately, unlike other image files like png

Tags: html, svg

My goal is to have a background image that would stretch to fill the entirety of the container  and stretch without keeping the ratio. I find that the following code would work with png files but not svg.

```
div
{
    background:url("/img/png/angle.png");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

So, that would work, but if I replace png with svg, it would keep its proportion, which is what you want most of the time, but not this particular time.

So, I don't absolutely have to use background-image. If using a img tag makes it work, I'll use that. All I want is for the image to stretch to fill and do NOT keep its proportion.

Comment: I'm not sure, would applying [`preserveAspectRatio` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) on `<svg>` help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` on the root `<svg>` element, that should make it work.